# Android notification: how to change font size

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am developing an android app. Would like to check whether it is possible to change the font size of notification in the code, and if yes, how to do it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a custom layout with different font sizes and using [Notification#setContent(RemoteViews r)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContent%28android.widget.RemoteViews%29)?